# Responsive two column grid

Tags: html, css, grid, flexbox

I am working on an animated web comic, for which I will make a few animated videos with different widths. My goal is to put the videos into a two-column grid that looks something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aclw5.jpg.

I am currently working on it with images instead of videos, just to see if it will even work.

I have tried it using flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/3zacce6e/5/

with this markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="flex-container">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/920x300">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/250x300">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/330x300">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/920x350">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
  <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
</div>
</div>
```

When you look at the grid layout with a viewport width of at least 934px (which is the biggest image plus the 7px margins on each side), this looks exactly the way I want. And then the images stack under each other at a breakpoint of 680px, which is also what I want.

The only problem I have are the viewport widths between 680px and the 934px. I would like the two-column layout to be responsive at these widths, and have the two-column-grid size down according to the viewport widths.

Is there any way to achieve what I want? I feel like I'm missing something really simple...

I very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just create rows for each actual row and make that `flex`. And wrap the images in a div since images as flex children stretch and respond weird.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 3vw;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container-video {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row > div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/920x300">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/250x300">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/330x300">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/920x350">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks perfect! The only problem I have now is that the media query to have the images stack under each other doesn't work anymore (see here: https://jsfiddle.net/qzz1khf4/1/). Do I maybe need to put a different selector than .container-video?

Comment: You, sir, are my new favorite person! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much, I appreciate your help!

Comment: There's one last thing I was wondering. Is it impossible to create something like this: http://imgur.com/CTD6CH9 using the markup that I've been using above? If I have three images in one row, they automatically stack next to each other, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qzz1khf4/4/. I'm guessing that there's no way that the two images on the right stack under each other?

Comment: So it does work! I have tried to do this for so long. Thank you so much!
I've realized that now the media query doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: This is weird, I just realized that when I use the code from before with the other media query it does work, it just doesn't work using the jsfiddle. But your solution works just as well! This was my last question, a big thank you for your kind help!

Comment: @L.Mayer cool, be sure and mark your question as solved if this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your result in multiple ways. One of them is by adding `Media queries` to your css for restyling between the width's. short example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 680px) and (max-width: 934px) {
   /* Extra CSS for styling the video's. */
   /* Example
     img.container-video {
      width: 50%;
}
}
```

A second example to achieve your goal is by using `bootstrap columns`
see the example below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <!-- img -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <!-- img -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <!-- img -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <!-- img -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <!-- img -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <!-- img -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <!-- img -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <!-- img -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <!-- img -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <!-- img -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

More information about bootstrap: [more](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

an example with an extra breakpoint using src attribute to select img tags :

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 3vw;
}

.flex-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-video {
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1018px) {
  .container-video {
    margin: auto auto 20px;
    max-width: 98%;
  }
  .container-video[src*="/600"] {
    max-width: 63%;
  }
  .container-video[src*="/450"] {
    max-width: 48%;
  }
  .container-video[src*="/300"] {
    max-width: 31%;
  }
  .container-video[src*="/330"] {
    max-width: 33%;
  }
  .container-video[src*="/250"] {
    max-width: 23%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .container-video[src*="/"] {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/920x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/250x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/330x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/920x350">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

This structure makes it easy since size can be easily retrieve  from src uri itself.

Another approach could be reordering them via `order` and only resize a few of them, or resize them them all to max-width:xx%

```css
  .wrapper {
  margin: 0 3vw;
}

.flex-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-video {
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1018px) {
  .container-video {
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 45%;
  }
  @media (max-width: 680px) {
    .container-video[src*="/"] {
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/920x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/250x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/330x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/920x350">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**for younger browser**, you can use the [`grid` CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 3vw;
}

.flex-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
  grid-gap:10px;
}


.container-video {
 margin:10px auto;
 width:100%;

}

.container-video[src*="/920"] {
  grid-column: auto / span 18;
}

.container-video[src*="/600"] {
  grid-column: auto / span 12;
}

.container-video[src*="/450"] {
  grid-column: auto / span 9;
}

.container-video[src*="/300"] {
  grid-column: auto / span 6;
}

.container-video[src*="/330"] {
  grid-column: auto/ span 7;
}

.container-video[src*="/250"] {
  grid-column: auto/ span 4;
}


}
@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .flex-container {
    display: block
  }
  
  .container-video {
    margin: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="flex-container">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/920x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/250x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/330x300">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/920x350">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
    <img class="container-video" src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
  </div>
</div>
```